# No resouce found error in layout

Tags: android

I tried to make use of a splash before starting an app . The image names match and doesnt show any errors in the xml file nor the java file.But the project shows the Error: No resource found that matches the given name 
These are the splash.java and splash.xml codes:
splash.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:src="@drawable/splash"
          android:layout_gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

splash.java:

```
package com.splash;
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;

 public class Splash extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);

int secondsDelayed = 1;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, menu.class));
                finish();
        }
}, secondsDelayed * 1000);
 }
 }
```

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: don get any error in any line.see a red cross at the project name. and a error in the console as :[2013-01-25 21:24:00 - splash] D:\New folder (2)\splash\res\layout\splash.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/splash').
But there is a png image with the name splash

Comment: ya i have an image in the drawable/hdpi folder named splash with a png extension .

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Try cleaning your project.

Comment: cleaned restrated eclipse .sadly  no  change

Comment: Sometimes recreating the R.java is the solution in such cases. Just delete gen/R.java. It's going to be recreated automatically.

Comment: Make a new folder under `res` called `drawable`, put your png in there and see if it works.

Comment: deleted r.java . it din get recreated early.. does it takle time ??

Comment: actually not more than a few seconds. do have any output in the console lie "R.java was removed! Recreating R.java!"

Comment: naa it dint.anyways i made anopther one . same error .failure in processing png image above the earlier error line .

Answer (score 0):

I have found this error in my application also. In my application I solved my problem by making the copy of the png image in all the folders of the drawables i.e. drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi. This works correctly in my application. Hope this will solve your problem.